# How to replace Android dictionary with our custom dictionary?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-userdictionary

I am developing an android app for doctors. The doctors needed to type only medicine name in an edit text. Keyboard predictive text suggestions are the best for my app for correcting the word. I have added the medicine names by adding words to user dictionary. But the keyboard uses these words along with default words.
I needed to give priority to user dictionary words, or let the app use only the words in the user dictionary or any other method.
I don't need autocompletextview. [image]